# How to delete selected rows from server and reload grid?

Tags: jqgrid, delete-row

Im trying to implement a jqgrid in my web page but not able to handle delete; if the user selects multiple values, and clicks on delete, I want to invoke a servlet that will handle the delete and return to the page.

The code snippet is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillGridOnEvent(){
    $("#jQGrid").html("<table id=\"list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyServletGrid?q=1&action=fetchData',
        datatype: "xml",
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 423,
        colNames:['##','Keyword','Category','ViewType',"Action"],
        colModel:[
            {name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:30,sortable:true,align:'center'},
            {name:'Keyword',index:'Keyword', width:200,sortable:true},
            {name:'Category',index:'Category', width:100,sortable:true,align:'center'},
            {name:'ViewType',index:'ViewType', width:100,sortable:true,align:'center'},
            {name:'view',index:'view', width:113,sortable:false,align:'center'}
        ],
        multiselect: true,
        paging: true,
        rowNum:18,
        pager: $("#page"),
        loadonce:true,
        caption: "Test JQGrid"
    }).navGrid('#page',{edit:false,add:false,del:true});
}
jQuery().ready(function (){
    //fillGrid();                    rowList:[10,20,30],
});
```

Comment: was you able to perform delete operation using jqgrid?

Answer (score -1):

Get the row id of the row to be deleted as follows

```
var rowid = jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
```

Get the row data using the following

```
var rowdata = jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
```

rowdata will have your data like rowdata.srNo, rowdata.Keyword etc.,

Issue an ajax call to your servlet for the delete from your database. Then call the following to reload your grid

```
jQuery("#tableid").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Im very new to JQGrid, can you please site me an example code or webpage where they have used JQGrid with JSP Servlet and basic functions - add, delete and edit.. ?

Comment: Please understand that jqGrid runs on the client side and servlet is a server technology. What you can do is to make ajax calls like the following.                                                   $.ajax({
            url: '/yoururl/add',
            type: 'get',
            async: false,
            data: { name: 'steve' },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("added successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
The "/yoururl/add" should be your servlet & will do your db insertions. you can do the rest.